# Checking for duplicate string in file java

Tags: java, android, io

I have an file, where I am writing data to it. I've tried googling, but all examples I have tried have just confused me more.
I am inputting data into a file, and this is happening correctly, where the items selected are being appended to the file. Where my issue is, is that I want to check whether the string being inputted already exists in the file, and if it does, I want to skip it.
The code I am using to input the data to the file is below, but I am not sure how to change it to check for a duplicate.

```
for (EventsObj p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
        if (p.box){
            String result = p.name + " " + p.price;

            try {
                // open file for writing
                OutputStreamWriter out= new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("UserEvents.txt",MODE_APPEND));
                // write the contents to the file
                out.write(result);
                out.write('\n');
                // close the file
                out.close();
            }

            catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                //do something if an IOException occurs.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry Text could't be added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
}
```

It is getting the checkboxes ticked, then getting the name and price related to it and appending it to file. But I want to carry out a check that this does not already exist. Any help would be appreciated and I've exhausted google and tried many things.

Comment: Have you considered using a database?  That would make it a lot easier to track what's there.

Comment: I did, but as there are only 10 items in the list I figured a simple I/O file would work, might look into a database a bit further

Comment: you would have to read the file before writing to it and check for a dupcliate. see no other way here

Comment: @TwelveDollar as I feared, I just hoped there might be a 'cleaner' way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understood your question correctly the file contains a number of strings delimited by newline.

What you want to do is to read the file contents line by line, and store the lines in a HashSet<String>. Then, you open the file for appending and append the additional string, but only if the file did not contain the string already. As the other answer suggested, you use the contains method. However, unlike the other answer I'm not suggesting to use a list of strings; instead, I'm suggesting the use of a HashSet as it's more efficient.

While reading the file contents line by line, you can perform some basic checks: does the file already contain duplicate rows? You may want to handle those by giving the user a warning that the file format is invalid. Or you may want to proceed nevertheless.

Comment: You would want to use a LinkedHashSet if you're concerned about maintaining the order of the strings.

Comment: Well, considering that the original poster is appending data to the end of the file, not rewriting the whole file, it shouldn't matter. But for rewriting the whole file, LinkedHashSet is really the only possibility.

Comment: Ah, OK I didn't notice he was only adding to the end.  Consider it just a generic note for anyone else reading this.

Comment: A HashSet worked perfectly. Used contain on each string that was being added, and if it contained the string, it doesn't get added. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly read from the file and create a list of strings with all your inputs.
Then before adding to the file you can check if the list of strings contains the string you want to add (just make sure that the strings share the same format such that a match will be found). If it returns false add to the file, if yes don't add to the file.

Shouldn't be such a tremendous task. You can make use of the [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) method.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to keep the contents of the file in a String in your program. A little inefficient, but at the moment I do not see any other way but to keep track of things in your program instead of on the file.
So before you run the program which appends text to the file, the very first thing you should probably do is parse the file for all text:

```
File yourFile = new File("file-path-goes-here");
Scanner input = null;

try {
    input = new Scanner (new FileInputStream(yourFile) );
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {;;;}

String textFromFile = "";
while (input.hasNextLine())
    textFromFile += input.nextLine() + "\n";

//Now before adding to the file simply run something like this
if(textFromFile.indexOf("string-to-write-to-file") != -1)
    ;//do not write to file
else {
    ;//write to file and add to textFromFile
    textFromFile += "string-you-added-to-file" + "\n";
}
```

Hope this answers your question. Let me know if something is not clear.